# Prevent Sublime 3 from converting tabs to spaces when pasting

Tags: sublimetext3

I've been using Sublime 3 on OSX for a while and auto-indentation generally works. I'm now working with XML files that has CDATA elements with tab separated values. When I paste anything into these CDATA elements Sublime keeps converting the tabs to spaces always. How can I prevent this?

I am using the default settings:

```
// The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
"tab_size": 4,

// Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,

// If translate_tabs_to_spaces is true, use_tab_stops will make tab and
// backspace insert/delete up to the next tabstop
"use_tab_stops": true,

// Set to false to disable detection of tabs vs. spaces on load
"detect_indentation": true,

// Calculates indentation automatically when pressing enter
"auto_indent": true,

// Makes auto indent a little smarter, e.g., by indenting the next line
// after an if statement in C. Requires auto_indent to be enabled.
"smart_indent": true,

// Adds whitespace up to the first open bracket when indenting. Requires
// auto_indent to be enabled.
"indent_to_bracket": false,

// Trims white space added by auto_indent when moving the caret off the
// line.
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
```

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TabNukerNuker

Comment: Thanks @r-stein! That plugin definitely solved it. I love the comments by the plugin creator.